# Grails Fields plugin - How to get datePicker to include constraints

Tags: grails, datepicker, grails-plugin, grails-2.1

Grails 2.1
Fields plugin 1.3

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the field rendering of Dates so that  will include the constraints (attributes) defined in the domain class.

Based on the [Fields plugin documentation](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html) and other information I have found, I should be able to do this through a default _input.gsp for Dates.
grails-app/views/_fields/date/_input.gsp

Currently the constraints are not being taken into account with the Fields plugin.
The following results in a date field with years beginning with 1912 through 2112:
birthDate( attributes: ["precision" : "day", "years" : 2016..1970])

This one results in a date field for Year, Month and Day even though the precision has been set to month and again, I get years 1912-2112:
expireDate(attributes: ["precision" : "month", "years" : 2007..2016])

How do I setup the _input.gsp to use the constraints for the datePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution, it may not be the best solution, but it is working for my app.

Using `grails-app/views/_fields/date/_input.gsp`

```
<%@ page defaultCodec="html" %>

<g:if test="${constraints.nullable == true}">
    <g:datePicker name="${property}" value="${value}" precision="${constraints.attributes.precision}" years="${constraints.attributes.years}" default="none" noSelection="['': '']" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
<g:datePicker name="${property}" value="${value}" precision="${constraints.attributes.precision}" years="${constraints.attributes.years}"/>
</g:else>
```